# Fantasy series about the rise of a magical/clerical sect

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I'm looking for a fantasy book series I read ca 2000 (IIRC, it was unfinished then).

- The story centered around political events in a kingdom and capital, and the rise of a magical/clerical sect.
- I vividly remember the first book dealing with a group of brothers taking a long voyage down a river, and stopping at a 'mystical' or forgotten island
- There was also, later on, a masked ball at said capital where someone was drowned

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a reach, but could the series be [*The Book of the New Sun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_the_New_Sun) by Gene Wolfe? It was not exactly unfinished by 2000 (it was published 1980–1983), but the follow-up *The Book of the Short Sun* was (which consists of three novels published 1999–2001).

[image: The Book of the New Sun]

> The story centered around political events in a kingdom and capital, and the rise of a magical/clerical sect.

Not a perfect fit, but perhaps an amalgamation of several plot threads? The series has a backdrop of political events in the kingdom called the Commonwealth and the city Nessus, seat of the Citadel and *de facto* capital.

There's not a rise of a sect *per se*, but there are several sects in the story. Notably, the main character Severian belongs to the Guild of Torturers (which is neither magical nor clerical), the female clerical sect of the Pelerines who worship a Messianic figure called the Conciliator, and a pervasive religious cult surrounding the coming of the "New Sun" common to the entire society. The Commonwealth is ruled by the Autarch, who is surrounded by a personality cult.

> I vividly remember the first book dealing with a group of brothers taking a long voyage down a river, and stopping at a 'mystical' or forgotten island

This could also fit several subplots in the series, although none of them feature brothers.

- In the first book, *The Shadow of the Torturer*, the main character Severian and his fellow torturer apprentices (who are like brothers to him; they have grown up together as fellow orphans) swim in Nessus's big river Gyoll, and Severian later travels on the river.
- In the second book, *The Claw of the Conciliator*, a fairy tale story-within-the-story called "The Tale of the Student and his Son" chronicles the titular son travelling on a ship to a mystical and uncharted island with many inland waterways to slay a monster (in a kind of retelling of the myth of Theseus and the Minotaur).
- In the third book, *The Sword of the Lictor*, Severian travels on the rivers of a city called Thrax.
- Also in the third book, Severian travels on a huge lake together with a group of natives who live on movable ship-islands, to reach a mystical castle.

> There was also, later on, a masked ball at said capital where someone was drowned

In the third book, *The Sword of the Lictor*, Severian works as a lictor, or bodyguard/executor, in the city of Thrax (so not the capital of Nessus, but still a major city). He attends a masked ball, and receives the order to execute a female guest by drowning. (Spoiler: He doesn't do it, but jumps into the water himself.)

Note also, since you referred to "the first book", that the four-book series has been released in two volumes as well, called *Shadow and Claw* (containing *The Shadow of the Torturer* and *The Claw of the Conciliator*) and *Sword and Citadel* (containing *The Sword of the Lictor* and *The Citadel of the Autarch*).

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Also a reach, but this reminds me of Katherine Kurtz's *In the King's Service*, the first book in her "Childe Morgan" trilogy, and one of the 16 novels set in the Deryni universe.

[image: Cover of "In the King's Service"]

Note that I read this and the other two books in the trilogy together, so I may be mixing memories across the trilogy as a whole.

The Deryni are (maybe) a special race with psychic/magical abilities. A couple of centuries before this book, Deryni had overthrown the king of the country followed in the series (Gwynedd), and ruled in their stead. A group of Deryni found the rightful human heir to the throne, killed the latest Deryni king (not a good guy), and reinstated human rule. Unfortunately, there was a strong backlash against the Deryni, and they are presently considered less than human (the church believes they don't have souls, or at least are damned).

However, the line of human kings was given access to Deryni powers, and the current king wants a Deryni companion to help his heir access those powers and learn to use them.

The story covers both the general history of the kingdom over the course of 5-10 years, and the events in the life of Alice of Corwyn (Alaric's mother).

There is a fair amount of river travel, though I can't recall an island of great significance.

However, the main reason I mention it is a drowning following a masked ball. I do not remember for certain if the celebration was actually a masked ball, but a Deryni child (the king's bastard son, though no one but he and the mother know that) is drowned in a well (suspended from a rope, and lowered in head first) - and a priest is involved.

Timing would just barely fit (published in 2003).

Has just enough similarity in that part at least to be worth mentioning.